# "No valid crumb was included in the request" running jenkins behind nginx server

Tags: nginx, jenkins

i trying to run a jenkins job from command line - but am getting this error inspite of adding a valid crumb to my curl ..

I have searched for answers everywhere but still havent been able to solve this issue.

my jenkins version is 2.60.2. I have tried ".crumb" , "Jenkins-Crumb" in the -H .. but to no avail.

Would appreciate any pointers/advice on this - thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be the answer is too late, but here is what worked for me:

Get the Crumb in JSON:

```
curl -s -u USER:API_TOKEN http://JENKINS_URL:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json
```

CURL POST to update an existing job

```
curl -X POST "http://USER:API_TOKEN@JENKINS_URL:8080/job/JOB_NAME/config.xml" -d "@Source_config.xml" -H "Jenkins-Crumb:CRUMB"
```